# Codeigniter Pagination URL issue

Tags: codeigniter

I just implemented pagination in my website [www.reviewongadgets.com](http://www.reviewongadgets.com)

When I click the home page it's divided into two pages which is correct but when I click on next link it shows the URL as

```
http://www.reviewongadgets.com/home/10
```

which is also correct but when I come back to previous page number it displays URL as

```
http://www.reviewongadgets.com/home/home/
```

So can you please help resolve this problem? Below is the controller snippet where `$url` is  `http://www.reviewongadgets.com/home`

```
$config['base_url'] = $url;
$config['total_rows'] = $this->MiscellaneousModel->countEntries();
$config['per_page'] = 10; 
$base_url = site_url('/');
$config['uri_segment'] = '2';
//$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be on how you define the base_url, since you give it a variable but you didn't tell where and how you assign a value to it. Try with:

```
$config['base_url'] = site_url('home');
$config['total_rows'] = $this->MiscellaneousModel->countEntries();
$config['per_page'] = 10; 
$config['uri_segment'] = '2';
```

Since you're using the index method, maybe specifying it can solve the issue (I had once a similar problem and that did work)

```
$config['base_url'] = site_url('home/index');
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you(famous last words)

```
//Add this to your routes
$route['home/(:num)'] = 'home/index/$1';


public function index($offset=0){

$limit = $this->config->item('pagination_per_page'); // default 10

//find data based on limits and offset
$query = //you query LIMIT = $limit OFFSET = $offset

$count = //count the number of rows returned by $query

//init pagination attributes
$config = array(
        'base_url' => site_url('home'),
        'total_rows' => $count,
        'per_page' => $limit,
        'uri_segment' => 2
    );
$this->pagination->initialize($config); 

//load the view and pagination data
$this->load->view('some_view', array(
        'pagination'  =>  $this->pagination->create_links(),
        'data'  => //data return from $query as object or array
));
}
```